# Error when using Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop

Tags: xna, c#

I'm trying to get the current location of the Desktop so that I can automate a few things in my game. The current problem though is that following line doesn't work after I publish but it works in visual studios 2010.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

I was wondering if there is a way around this.

Comment: Hey and welcome to the community. I think your question requires a bit more detail. I. E. What kind of error are you getting? What does your code look like? When you walk through it with a debugger what doe the value of Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop contain? Are you attempting to run as a user without admin rights?

Comment: Are you publishing it for Windows? If so, I'm unable to reproduce - it works both in Visual Studio and when published for me (I'm creating a file on desktop). Attach the debugger and tell us what you see.

Comment: Side note: I don't like games that mess with my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop is not supported by the XNA Framework.

The table here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Shows the first column indicating if the XNA Framework supports it.

Supported:

- ApplicationData
- Favorites
- Programs
- StartMenu
- Startup
- Personal

Comment: However, for Windows it does work in both cases (Visual Studio and Publish), and there's no reason it shouldn't seeing how it's all .NET anyway.